# Отправка уведомлений пользователю при полностью выключенном приложении

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, уведомления, android-notification

Нужно чтобы даже после полностью выключенного приложения пользователем, приходили уведомления от node сервера. Пытался сделать через BroadcastReciever и Service, но они выводят только если приложение находится в фоне. Рассматриваю вариант с Firebase messages, но не могу до конца понять, будет ли это работать при полностью выключенном приложении. Если есть варианты, как можно это сделать по другому, то подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении идти.

Answer (score 0):

Описанная вами проблема наблюдается преимущественно на устройствах китайских производителей(например: **Huawei, Oppo, Xiaomi**).

Эти телефоны имеют особую причуду: когда приложение принудительно закрывается, вы больше не сможете получать уведомления, пока приложение не будет перезапущено. Для того чтобы вы могли получать фоновые уведомления:

- На вашем устройстве **Huawei** перейдите в «Настройки»> «Защищенные приложения» и выберите «Мое приложение».
- На вашем **Xiaomi** убедитесь, что на вашем телефоне включено свойство "Автозапуск" для вашего приложения.
- На вашем **Asus** убедитесь, что на вашем телефоне включено свойство «Автозапуск» для вашего приложения.

Более подробно смотрите на сайте [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bensin/2017/07/28/how-to-fix-push-notifications-on-oppo-phones/#3cb05b541735)